# $\lim_{x\to 3} (x−3)f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions

I need help with a calculus/limit problem.

I suppose I am looking for a function that:

- $f(x)$ such that it has $(x-3)^2$ in the denominator
- $f(x)$ such that $f(x)(x-3)$ equals $y=x-3$.

I struggle to understand how the above is possible. How is it possible to have a function that:

- $\lim_{x \to 3} f(x) = \infty$
- $\lim_{x \to 3} (x-3)f(x) = 0$

Any help or pointers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp or $\frac{\sqrt{|x-3|}}{|x-3|}$

Comment: So this is a stupid question, but for a limit to exist without specifying from which side we approach the x, it has to approach the same value from both sides. Doesn't that mean any square root function would not have  a two-sided limit because of the imaginary part of the function?

Comment: A quick way to turn a square root into a two-sided function is to throw in an absolute value. For instance, $|x-3|^{-1/2}$ would satisfy your conditions. And I now realize that is what @HagenvonEitzen suggested. Whoops haha.

Comment: Yet another option is $f(x)=-\log|x-3|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$f(x)={1\over \sqrt[3]{(x-3)^2}}$$

then $$\lim _{x\to 3}(x-3)f(x)=   \lim _{x\to 3} {\sqrt[3]{x-3}} = 0$$

and $$\lim _{x\to 3 }f(x) = \infty$$